# Python not running from cmd in Windows 8 after upgrade

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I can run the command line version of Python but I cannot seem to run it from the command prompt. I have recently upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 8 and it worked fine with Windows 7. Now Windows 8 will not recognize Python. Thanks, William

Comment: Did you put it into your PATH environment variable? It doesn't do this automatically as far as I remember. http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables

Comment: @TheZ: For the 3.3 release, an option was added to set the executable's directory in `PATH`, but it's not enabled as a default.

Comment: @eryksun Oh? It's about time they made it easier for people to do that. It's quite a scary proposition to instruct a novice on how to edit their path variable... a lot can go wrong... a surprising amount of wrong.

Comment: @TheZ: 3.3 also adds shebang support to run a script in a particular interpreter, or starting different interpreters in the console with `py -2`, `py -2.6`,`py -3`, etc.

Comment: @eryksun My god... I really need to get 3.3 and read the changelogs! Sounds like a lot of great stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it works from the Menu Item but not from the command prompt is that the menu item specifies the `"Start in"` directory where the Python executable can be found.

Chances are the Win 7 -> Win 8 upgrade failed to preserve the PATH environmental variable, where the path the Python was previously specified, allowing you to invoke Python from *any* command prompt console.

Answer (score 1):

I installed as follows:

- Python 3.3.2 Windows X86-64 MSI Installer
- Windows 8
- "Install for All Users"
- turned on "Add python.exe to Path"

When I had completed, Python did not execute from a command shell.

I checked the environment variables, and, sure enough, "C:\Python33\", where I had installed it, was in the System environment variables.

But for some reason, "python" would only invoke Python at the command shell if I opened an administrator's command shell -- opening a non-privileged command shell would not include C:\Python33\ in the path.

My workaround was to create a PATH environment variable with value "C:\Python33" as a User variable, and then it worked.

There may be other ways to do this.  For example, rebooting or logging out & in may be worth trying.

See also:

- http://bugs.python.org/issue3561 -- long Python discussion on what to do about the Windows path, and the pragmatics it
- http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/wise-7-win-7-problems-updating-environment-variable-current-user -- further Internet discussion on issues involving path

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to C:\python33 or wherever you installed it.
2. Right click on "pythonw" and pin to taskbar,
3. Run from taskbar.